# iframe - global is not defined

Tags: javascript, vue.js, iframe, vite

I have an application(Vue3/Vite) that requires a polyfill to make an [SDK](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@walletconnect/client) work. All is well until one of our customers wants to use the application inside of an iframe. Once that happens, we lose the `globalThis` polyfill.

Inside of my application, I have this set in the `vite.config.js` file:

```
export default defineConfig({
  // Other config stuff
  optimizeDeps: {
    esbuildOptions: {
      define: {
        global: "globalThis",
      },
      plugins: [
        NodeGlobalsPolyfillPlugin({
          buffer: true,
        }),
      ],
    },
  },
});
```

Is it possible to extend this, so the iframe doesn't lose context?

Side note, in order to test implementation inside of an iframe, I've spun up a web app, the same stack as my customer, and I cannot get it to work even after adding the polyfill to my demo application, thinking it may inherit it from the top window.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

I found a workaround.

The SDK I'm using doesn't work well with Vite. So after looking into CDNs and unpackaging solutions, I saw someone mention importing the `udm` version of the package. That ended up working, and I removed the polyfill from the project.

I was able to import each like so:

`import WalletConnect from "@walletconnect/client/dist/umd/index.min.js";`

`import QRCodeModal from "@walletconnect/qrcode-modal/dist/umd/index.min.js";`